# Fast bitcoin load service

Tags: payment, services

I'm freelancer and I'm willing to get paid with bitcoins. Hence I need to find some service which allows to top up bitcoin wallet with minimum efforts (even without registration). Something similar to: https://paynow.payoneer.com/ (but for bitcoins). Simplicity is really important.

May anyone suggest some?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you're trying to find something to recommend your customers in order for them to buy bitcoins to pay you?

Comment: @Murch yes, correct. But ideally they don't even need to know the word 'bitcoin'. Any of those 'computer stuff things' freak them out really well. It would be great if my client could fill some simple form like: their email address, my bitcoin address, amount to pay, credit card info.

Answer (score 0):

There was a great service back in the day called https://www.moneypacket.org/. You can send bitcoin with email. I think it still works so it seems like a great solution to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I made the wallet [Bolt](https://vladimirtahl.github.io/bolt/#), and it is extremely simple.

It does not need registration.

All you have to do is generate your address and save a file.

That file could be encrypted or not.

Every time you open the link you should import that file.

Comment: Does not answer the question, OP was looking for a service to buy bitcoin on.